# Not able to see newly added child nodes for a already placed node in arkit swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am adding a chair node to the `sceneView`. Later I want to add a telephone node onto the chair node which means I want to add telephone as a child node to a chair.

I initially performed hittest. If the `sceneView.hittest.first.node` is present then I would like to place a telephone 3d model onto chair 3dmodel. So I added a line of code `node.addChildNode(newNode)`. It adds a new node to child nodes array of the node. But I cannot see it in `cameraView`.

```
guard  let scence = recognizer.view as? ARSCNView else { return }

   let touch = recognizer.location(in: scence)

   let results = sceneView.hitTest(touch, options: [.boundingBoxOnly: true])

   guard let node = results.first?.node

   if let hitTest = results.first
   {

     let chairScene = SCNScene(named: string)

     guard let chairNode = chairScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "parentnode", recursively: true)else{return}

     chairNode.position = SCNVector3(hitTest.localNormal.x,hitTest.localNormal.y,hitTest.localNormal.z) 

     node.addChildNode(chairNode)
```

I am able to add newnode to children of node.But newnode 3dmodel is not visible in camera view.